# DolphinDB: Calculate R2 in sliding window

Tags: calculation, dolphindb, sliding-window

For 2 matrices of the same size, I'd like to perform `ols` on each corresponding column. How to calculate r2 in sliding window?
`moving` is not suitable as it requires aggregate functions but `ols` is not.
The window size is 20 and I hope the output is like `mbeta`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own aggregate func for ols R2 with `defg`, just like:

```
defg myolsr2(y, x) {
    rs = ols(y, x, true, 2).RegressionStat
    d = dict(rs.item, rs.statistics)
    return d['R2']
}
```